# 312.6 interpretation when entering from the back of panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, code-compliance, nec

312.6 lists (A) and (B) tables, for when NOT enterting oposite and entering on opposite wall of the box.

How is the entering through the back wall interpretted?

Technically it would be "NOT opposite" but it feels silly that it has less stringent dimentions? (and the code's defined measurement seems hard to conduct this way unless one has to measure from the lug perpendicular to the back wall??).
(Actually, I do not undrestand why entering on opposite wall has bigger space requirements - do not most feeders enter right on top/front of the subpannel lugs with almost no deflection/bend?).

Comment: I have found a very "in-depth" discussion here: https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/4-0-cable-into-the-back-of-a-3-1-2-inch-deep-panel.13178/page-2
Whereby sombody got a reply from Sqare-D that interpretation of measurement of distance is "to nearest wall/obstruction" and not necesarely to the entry point's (KO) wall?

Comment: And that is interesting: Code Cycle 2008 314.28(A) (2) Exception: Where a raceway or cable entry is in the wall of a box or conduit body opposite a removable cover, the distance from that wall to the cover shall be permitted to comply with the distance required for one wire per terminal in table 312.6(A)

Comment: The amount of tension on the terminals / or insulation at the entry point is the issue and if the entry is not opposite the terminals there is usually a loop reducing the tension on the terminals as the wire size increases there is also a requirement for a insulated neck / bushing or smooth rounded surface so the insulation is not compromised on a sharp conductive surface.  If you look at all the verbiage I believe this is the focus of the article.